# webgl: Variable Not Passed To Shader Which Results in Magic?

Tags: javascript, webgl

A vertex array representing a triangle is never passed to the vertex shader with getAttribLocation / vertexAttribPointer. However, A Triangle will still draw on the screen. How is the triangle being drawn. In the shader I specify vec2 pos, but I never use getAttribLocation. Is vec2 position a reserved value in GLSL?  :

```js
function createShader( str, type ) {
  var shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
  gl.compileShader(shader);

  return shader;
}

function createProgram(vstr, fstr) {
  var program = gl.createProgram();
  var vshader = createShader(vstr, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  var fshader = createShader(fstr, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.attachShader(program, vshader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fshader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  return program;
}
  
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var gl = c.getContext('experimental-webgl');
var vertexPosBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPosBuffer);
var vertices = [ -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0, 0.5];
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var vs = 'attribute vec2 asdf;' +
         'attribute vec2 pos;' +
         'void main() { gl_Position = vec4( pos, 0, 1 ); }';

var fs = 'precision mediump float;' +
         'void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(0,0.8,0,1); }';

var program = createProgram(vs,fs);
gl.useProgram(program);

//
function animate () {
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

The GL will assign locations for each attribute, no matter if you query them or not. However, you only have one active attribute, since `asdf` has no effect whatsoever and will be optimized away. So it is very likely (but not guaranteed) that `pos` ends up as attribute `0`.

Even if `asdf` were used, there still would be the chance that it ends up as `0`, as the mapping between attribute names and locations is totally implementation-specific.

The recommendation is of course: don't do that. Either, assign the locations yourself via `glBindAttribLocation` (before linking the program), or query what the GL has assigned, otherwise the behavior will vary with each implementation.

Comment: Where does it state this in the ES 2.0 Spec.

Comment: @SteveWebster: ES spec 2.0.25, section 2.10.4 "Shader Variables", subsection "Vertex Attributes", pages 32-34.

Comment: The Spec does not mention the GLSL optimization or how the mapping is "implementation specific".

Comment: @SteveWebster: The spec explicitely talks about _active_ attributes and about the locations being assinged _by the GL_, if not explicitely assigned by the user.